# Posting free text to SOLR

Tags: solr

I am exploring `SOLR Cloud` as one of the potential solutions to indexing a lot of random log based text and searching the same. I have a basic question about posting log files data to `SOLR`.

First few fields in any log statement are important fields (`timestamp`, `severity`, etc) which are separated by space bar. How do we tell `SOLR` where these fields end and where free text begins (which itself has many space characters in it)?

An e.g could be:
"*Timestamp ModuleName Severity messageId* A lot of free text which will be space delimited."

If I am able to add free text to `SOLR`, how can I search on it? I think `SOLR` will not allow me searching on free text because it is not a part of its index. If so, then how can I get some portions of my free text indexed as well? So, there could be some fields out of free text also which are of interest and I may want to search on them as well.

Say, a statement like:

"*Timestamp ModuleName Severity messageId* - A lot of free text which will be space delimited but contains *externalResponseValue* to be also searchable but not all log lines will have it and its position also is not fixed within a line where it appears."

Thanks!

Sumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) :-

Use the [LineEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LineEntityProcessor) to process the log file line by line
Use the [RegexTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer) to the split the line into the fragments and populate fields with these accordingly.
This would include all the data in individual fields. If you index the text field that would make it searchable.

Comment: Thank you Jayendra. I took some time to read through this suggestion and while I am still unable to fully get it to work, I think your suggestion is valid.

Thanks!

Comment: What issues are you facing ?

Comment: Just to clarify more, the problem I am not able to solve yet is that clients can post data to my SOLR cloud directly. 
Which means I cannot run any pre-processing at their end to use LineEntityProcessor. Here is how they post to us:

http://<SOLR CLOUD>:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true&fieldnames=time,class,log&separator=%20" --data-binary @Some_server.log -H "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8"

Fields "time", "class" and "log" are indexed. Here "log" is the one which contains free text.